# Java Stream sorted() to generic List

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

I have a List called "catalog" of Articles (generic Type).

An Article has following Methods:

```
public int getUnitsInStore()
public long getUnitPrice()
```

Now i want to sort this list by the total value of a single Article (units * pricePerUnit) using Java Stream sorted().

I've tried:

```
catalog = catalog.stream()
    .map(a -> a.getUnitPrice() * a.getUnitsInStore())
    .sorted((a, b)->a.compareTo(b))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(List<Article>::new));
```

But its giving me following error:

```
Cannot instantiate the type List<Article>
```

What i'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
I've also tried:

```
catalog = catalog.stream()
    .map(a -> a.getUnitPrice() * a.getUnitsInStore())
    .sorted((a, b)->b.compareTo(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It says:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Long> to List<Article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
catalog = catalog.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getUnitPrice() * a.getUnitsInStore()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also sort in reverse order.

```
catalog = catalog.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Article a) -> a.getUnitPrice() * a.getUnitsInStore()).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is solving my Problem. Can you tell me how to sort it reverse? With the greatest value at first

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm really grateful

Answer (score 2):

You can't do `new List()`, so you can't do `List::new`. It's an interface. It can't be instantiated.

If you were to change it to `ArrayList<Article>::new`, you wouldn't get that error.

However

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Article>::new));
```

is basically just a more verbose way of using a type witness:

```
.collect(Collectors.<Article>toList());
```

All that said, Java should also be able to infer the type from the assignment. If the stream is `Stream<ArticleParent>` and you are trying to assign to `List<Article>`, it should be able to infer that. You've omitted the declaration of the field, so I'll assume that you're right that the compiler cannot infer it correctly for some reason.

Comment: This is giving me the error: "The method collect(Collector<? super Long,A,R>) in the type Stream<Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<Article,capture#1-of ?,List<Article>>)"

Comment: Michael, I believe you are missing the `map` (and the method signature used within) step in the OPs question which is the cause of the error variants shared by them.